# large number of variables cause error on submission of form in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have got a pretty big php form named "form.php" to be submitted . i can estimate it having around 1800 input fields or variables in it. While i submit the page it gives me following error :

403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /file.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

where 'file.php' is in action of the 'form.php'.

I should clarify here that. the same code was running on a different server very fine.
and that I tried to lessen down the variables by deleting more than half part of form for testing purpose, I would say up to about 400 variables it submitted successfully.

also I tried to edit some ini settings as following but still nothing good.

```
post_max_size = 50M
max_input_vars = 9000
realpath_cache_size = 32K
upload_max_filesize = 6M
max_execution_time = 60
```

please help me on this matter.
thanx.

cPanel Version  11.42.1 (build 25)
PHP version     5.4.30
Apache version  2.4.9
Perl version    5.10.1

Comment: What are the permissions of file.php when you look on your server's FTP ?

Comment: permissions of both files were 0644, I also changed them to 0755 . but still nothing.

Comment: Maybe it's related to http://edrackham.com/javascript/solution-to-form-submit-403-error/

Comment: no its not related to that one, no url field present. as I have written, if i cut down the form to about 400 variables , it submits. its only about the size of form.

Comment: Maybe some security system filtering the request. Take a look at all relevant log files (PHP, webserver, maybe firewall) to see whats blocking your requests.

Comment: When you try to send only 1 input field, it works ?

Comment: yes. when i send only 1 input field , or upto 300 to 400 fields , it works, but more than 400 fields causes the error.

Comment: more than 400 variables or fields, cause you can store all the inputs in one object/array and pass that?

Answer (score 1):

I drilled down to the problem , and it was due to the matter that One of Mod security rule was conflicting with my domain , i disabled it . and now my page works very fine.